# How do I sum values based on lookup from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that is tracking sales. Most often, I care about the SKU but I'm also trying to get revenue numbers based on categories as well. There are many sales per SKU, and many SKUs per category. Below are some simplified examples of the sheets I have.

SKUs sheet

| SKU | Category |
| --- | --- |
| prodA | cat1 |
| prodB | cat2 |
| prodC | cat1 |
| prodD | cat2 |

Sales Sheet

| SKU | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| prodA | 3.00 |
| prodB | 1.50 |
| prodA | 2.75 |
| prodC | 1.25 |
| prodA | 1.50 |
| prodB | 5.00 |
| prodD | 1.50 |

Performance Sheet

| SKU | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| prodA | 7.25 |
| prodB | 6.50 |
| prodC | 1.25 |
| prodD | 1.50 |

At this point, I basically want to get the unique categories from the SKUs sheet, find all SKUs in each category, then sum the totals of those SKUs from the performance sheet. Is there a way to do this all in a single cell? Do I need to create some kind of intermediate sheet? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: What about simple `QUERY()` function. `=QUERY(A2:B,"select A, sum(B) group by A")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula. It first finds the unique categories (you may change that first line to other range if you have it already sorted. Then with BYROW lists each value with the sum of the products, filtered by the correspondence with the categories with XLOOKUP

```
=LET(cat,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(SKU!B2:B,1))),
BYROW(cat,LAMBDA(each, 
 {each, SUM(FILTER(Sales!B2:B,XLOOKUP(Sales!A2:A,SKU!A2:A,SKU!B2:B)=each))})))
```

[image]

Or, a similar process with QUERY:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(XLOOKUP(Sales!A2:A,SKU!A2:A,SKU!B2:B,)),Sales!B2:B},"SELECT Col1,SUM(Col2) Where Col1 is not null group by Col1 LABEL Col1 'Categories', SUM(Col2) 'Sum'",)
```

[image]